# Multiple options in broker url - correct syntax

Tags: spring, activemq-classic

I have an embedded broker as follows;

```
<bean id="Server1_remote" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="failover:(tcp://server1:61616,tcp://server1:61616)?keepAlive=true" />
</bean>
```

All works well, but I need to add some more options to the failover connection.

If I do;

```
<bean id="Server1_remote" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="failover:(tcp://server1:61616,tcp://server1:61616)?keepAlive=true&initialReconnectDelay=5000" />
</bean>
```

It fails to start the server and errors with;

> ERROR:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Line 108 in XML document from class path resource [activemq.xml] is
>   invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
>   lineNumber: 108; columnNumber: 132; The reference to entity
>   "initialReconnectDelay" must end with the ';' delimiter.

Ok - so If I do `"?keepAlive=true&initialReconnectDelay=5000;"` I still get the same error.

Have also tried (After noticing the subtle differenced between [these](http://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html) 2 [pages](http://activemq.apache.org/tcp-transport-reference.html));

```
<bean id="Server1_remote" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="failover:(tcp://server1:61616?transport.tcpNoDelay=true&transport.keepAlive=true,tcp://server1:61616?transport.tcpNoDelay=true&transport.keepAlive=true)?initialReconnectDelay=5000" />
</bean>
```

I've had a look through the AMQ website and couldn't see one [example](http://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html) of multiple options in a string?!?!

Can someone please tell me the correct syntax to use so that I'm able to set multiple options, and or point to towards a clear example somewhere.

For completeness, the other part of the bridged connection is;

```
<jmsBridgeConnectors>
    <jmsTopicConnector name="server1_feeds" outboundTopicConnectionFactory="#Server1_remote" >
        <inboundTopicBridges>
            <inboundTopicBridge consumerName="vm0-topic1" inboundTopicName="TOPIC1"
            localTopicName="TOPIC1_OUT" />
        </inboundTopicBridges>
    </jmsTopicConnector>
</jmsBridgeConnectors>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're getting is coming from Spring, not from any ActiveMQ code. The exception is `org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException` which is due to some kind of Spring configuration problem and not your ActiveMQ URL syntax.

I believe your problem is with the `&` character which you've added to your configuration. It needs to be escaped in XML as `&amp;` since it is a reserved character.

Comment: Feel free to edit in a way that makes the most sense. I've cleaned up my comments.